# Counting the number of remaining weeks in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I'd like to be able to calculate how many weeks from a given date in the future until today are available. But I can't find out how to do this. I found `WEEKNUM`, but that only gives me the calendar number of a week. I need the sum of total weeks, given a specific date in the future, from today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DUR2WEEKS function. Here is a screenshoot from an example:

[image]